# Using supertabular, how do I create a single column table in a 2 column document?

Tags: two-column, supertabular

My document has 2 columns. I am trying to create a table that has a single column (i.e. a single entry in each line) but can split across both columns of the document, and even go to the next page.
I am using supertabular, which I only half understand, and at this point, I have written this

```
\documentclass[12pt,aps,prb,twocolumn, nofootinbib]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{%
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\tbsp Number}
\hline}
%

\tablehead{%
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\tbsp Number}
\hline}
%
\tabletail{%
\midrule \multicolumn{1}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \midrule}

\begin{supertabular}{l}
    \hline
    42\\ \hline
    347\\ \hline
\end {supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which does not work, instead it gives me a lot of errors and it is unable to compile. What am I doing wrong, and is there a better/simpler way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Also please extend your snippet to a complete document that can be compiled and tested directly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a few `\\` - \hline should come always after a it. And `\tbsp` is not defined, so I removed it. With this changes your example compiles fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aps,prb,twocolumn, nofootinbib]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{%
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ Number}
\\\hline}
%%
%
\tablehead{%
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ Number}
\\\hline}
%%
\tabletail{%
\midrule \multicolumn{1}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \midrule}

\begin{supertabular}{l}
    \hline
    42\\ \hline
    347\\ \hline
\end {supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your table will fit in single page, then you can try with:

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{...}
\begin{tabular}{..}
...
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

No need to go with `supertabular` or `longtable`, which are mainly used for tables which exceeds more than a page...